# Use Serial Monitor on Platformio not show tty.usbmodem

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I am new to use [platformio IDE](http://platformio.org) on develop arduino. I was use Arduino UNO. On initialize, i have add this platform-arduino uno. But i dont see port tty.usbmodem1411. What should i do ?
There is output if i cek with pio serialports

```
$ pio serialports list
/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
-------------------------------
Hardware ID: n/a
Description: n/a

/dev/cu.NunungsiPad-WirelessiAP

-------------------------------
Hardware ID: n/a
Description: n/a

/dev/cu.usbmodem1411
--------------------
Hardware ID: USB VID:PID=2341:0043 SER=95233353131351C08162 LOCATION=20-1
Description: Generic CDC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Platformio the initial port on USB is `/dev/cu.usbmodem1411`. It just different name.

So it will work with serial monitor - you can try with shift+command+M or form menu platformio --> serial monitor